why is my SpriteKit collision detection not working properly?
I am making a SpriteKit platformer game and I am trying to get the collision detection working. so far I have written this code to detect when the player hits a tiles physics body:
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if let playerNode = (contact.bodyA.node as? SKSpriteNode), let wallNode = (contact.bodyB.node) {
        print("Collision detected between player and wall")
        print("Player position: \(playerNode.position), Wall position: \(wallNode.position)")
        handleCollision(player: playerNode, wall: wallNode)
    } else if let playerNode = (contact.bodyB.node as? SKSpriteNode), let wallNode = (contact.bodyA.node) {
        print("Collision detected between player and wall")
        print("Player position: \(playerNode.position), Wall position: \(wallNode.position)")
        handleCollision(player: playerNode, wall: wallNode)
    }
}


func handleCollision(player: SKSpriteNode, wall: SKNode) {
    guard wall.physicsBody != nil else {
        print("Wall physics body is nil")
        return
    }
    
    let playerRect = player.frame
    let wallRect = wall.frame
    
    let diffX = playerRect.midX - wallRect.midX
    let diffY = playerRect.midY - wallRect.midY
    
    print("PlayerRect: \(playerRect), WallRect: \(wallRect)")
    print("diffX: \(diffX), diffY: \(diffY)")
    
    if abs(diffX) > abs(diffY) {
        // Horizontal collision
        if diffX > 0 {
            // Player is to the right of the wall
            player.position.x = wallRect.maxX + playerRect.width / 2
            print("Adjusting player to the right of the wall")
        } else {
            // Player is to the left of the wall
            player.position.x = wallRect.minX - playerRect.width / 2
            print("Adjusting player to the left of the wall")
        }
    } else {
        // Vertical collision
        if diffY > 0 {
            // Player is above the wall
            player.position.y = wallRect.maxY + playerRect.height / 2
            print("Adjusting player above the wall")
        } else {
            // Player is below the wall
            player.position.y = wallRect.minY - playerRect.height / 2
            print("Adjusting player below the wall")
        }
    }
    
    // Reset the player's velocity to prevent floating or sliding
    player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    print("Player velocity reset to zero")
}

The code works for the bottom and left edges, but there is always a gap that I cannot cross on the right and bottom edges.
I have tried to take out the sides that aren't working, expecting to see the player pass through the tile from those directions, however I did this and there was zero effect. I have also checked for invisible pixels in my images but as far as I could see, nothing was off in that respect. The print("collision detected between player and wall") statement goes off when the player collides with the area around the wall that I cannot pass, meaning it could be something to do with the collision detection.

Try setting the showsPhysics property on the SKView. Likely you've got your physics bodies not aligned with your graphics. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520389-showsphysics

As @bg2b said, + provide the rest of the code for the player and wall so we can run a test.
